# How to create a custom object with apex for apex scheduler? (Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types)

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, scheduler, visualforce

I am new to apex and am trying to build an apex schedule class that runs everyday. If the account review date for commisions is two weeks (14 days) away the scheduler will send an email to our Sales Department.

I'm almost done with the program but I keep getting this error:

Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, Date at line 9 column 9

Here is my code:

```
global class AccountReviewScheduler implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) 
    {
        sendEmail();
    }
public void sendEmail()
{
    if (Account__r.Next_Account_Review_Date__c == System.today().addDays(14))
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        Mail.setTemplateId('00XF0000000LfE1');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });
    }
}

}
```

I did some research and a commenter on another discussion board told me that it's not working because
Account__r.Next_Account_Review_Date__c is just a field.

I have to use it with a record to make it have a value. Then I can compare that value with system.today().

I'm not sure what that means....create a custom object? I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my revised code I'm having trouble with. Here is my revised code:

Here is the revised code(asterisks ** denote change)

```
global class AccountReviewScheduler implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) 
    {
        sendEmail();
    }
public void sendEmail()
{
    **CustomObj__c co = [select Account__r.Next_Account_Review_Date__c from CutomObj__c limit 1];**
    **if(co.Account__r.Next_Account_Review_Date__c == system.today().addDays(14))** 
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        Mail.setTemplateId('00XF0000000LfE1');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });
    }
}

}
```

Changes are shown in bold...I know the custom obj code might be wrong...I got it off someone else and I'm not sure what to do.

NOTE: Time based workflows will not work here because this email has to occur every year (for many years) 14 days before the account review date. Time based workflows will work ONCE after they are set to trigger one year, but do not repeat. They do not recur by design. See: http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000JnPMEA0

I have read the scheduling documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

and gone over the Apex workbook tutorial:http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2010/02/spring-10-saw-the-general-availability-of-one-of-my-favorite-new-features-of-the-platform-the-apex-schedulerwith-the-apex-s.html as well as tutorial 14 in the official Apex guide but I still am having trouble.

Any help/insight into my code/links to new resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `Account__r.Next_Account_Review_Date__c` using this in this situation it is just a field token is doesn't reference any data. This token is used with the schema/metadata methods in Apex to get information about the field itself, such as it's type, label etc. This section of the help should shed some more light on that subject for you http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

The reason that you're having this problem is that you're not selecting any data from the database to work on. I would guess that your send email method would work if it looked more like this

```
public void sendemail(){
  for(Account acc : [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Next_Review_Date__c = :system.today().addDays(14)]){

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTemplateId('00XF0000000LfE1');
    mail.setTargetObjectId(acc.Id);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });


  }

}
```

This will select all accounts that have a Next Review Date equals to 14 days time. It will then loop over them and send the email. I have presumed that the Next_Review_Date__c field is on the Account object and I have also assumed that the email template needs the Account that's due in order to create itself successfully.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I have revised my code but now I have this error: Error: Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'EOF' at line 0 column -1...I'm confused where this is...line o?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you really want to do here is a us a batchable interface along with a schedulable interface.

The schedule interface will let you execute the batch interface. You will want to use a batch interface so that your code will scale with the number of accounts that could be in a state beyond the 14 day notification window. The bare bones code for that would look like this:

```
global without sharing class AccountReviewScheduler implements 
Database.Batchable<sObject>
, Database.Stateful, Schedulable
{
//Batchable Methods
global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bcContext) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT 
                                        Id
                                        , Next_Account_Review_Date__c 
                                    FROM 
                                        Account 
                                    WHERE 
                                        Next_Account_Review_Date__c = :System.today().addDays(14)]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bcContext, List<sObject> listAccounts)
{
    for (sObject oSObject : listAccounts) {
        Account oAccount = (Account) oSObject;

        //Build a list of email messages here
    }

    //Send Email Here
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bcContext) {}

//Schedulable Methods
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new AccountReviewScheduler());
}
}
```

You email logic would be in the batch execute method which will process the accounts in batches. With each batch having its own context in terms of governor limits. You can change the batch size but by default it processes 200 records at a time.

Here is a link to some documentation on the batch interface that should help fill in some of the blanks.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm